# Validating users input between min and max using a function

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to make a function that asks the user for a number in between whatever number is passed to the functions min and max, eg.(1,10) I can't seem to get it to work though, what am I missing/ doing wrong here?

```
function getProductChoice(min, max) {

    do {
        var productIndex = parseInt(prompt('Enter your product choice', '0'));
    } while( isNaN(productIndex) || productIndex <= max || productIndex >= min);

    getProductChoice(1,6);
 };
```

Comment: Your `while` condition should contain *"bad"* outcomes. For `min` and `max` it doesn't.   Plus move function call outside of the function. Right now you have endless recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to stop prompting when the given number satisifies the range. However, your current code does the opposite, continuing to run when the `productIndex` is less than the max or greater than the min. Try switching your `max` and `min` in the conditional.

In this example I've also pulled the `getProductChoice()` function call out of the function, as recursion is not necessary.

```
function getProductChoice(min, max) {
    do {
        var productIndex = parseInt(prompt('Enter your product choice', '0'));
    } while( isNaN(productIndex) || productIndex <= min || productIndex >= max);
 };
 getProductChoice(1,6);
```